# Using keys to identify nested components in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to prevent a component from calling all its lifecycle when "moving" it from one context to another?

Originally, I had a list of components, keyed by id. This was useful, because when I would reorder the list, the components wouldn't re-call all the lifecycle methods, they would just "move".

It became apparent that my design had to move from [Widget] to [Row], where Row = [Widget].
Items now move from Row to Row, but have the same ID the whole time. Regardless, all (including componentWillMount) the lifecycle methods are being called when the component moves to the new context.

Is it possible to identify a component globally within the entire render context to prevent this behavior? Or Is there another design I should pursue?

```
[       ][       ][       ] <- rows, don't care
 |||||||  |||||||  |||||||  <- significant
       ^ <- this
[      ][        ][       ] 
 ||||||  ||||||||  |||||||
         ^ <- should be able to move
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying keys for Rows also?

Comment: Yeah, the rows are largely ceremonial, so I tried keying them by the iteration index. Doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconciliation algorithm is explained in detail in the documentation:
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

From what I understand reading it, you can not accomplish what you want:

> In the current implementation, you can express the fact that a
>   sub-tree has been moved amongst its siblings, but you cannot tell that
>   it has moved somewhere else. The algorithm will re-render that full
>   sub-tree.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I would be nice if you could specify a reconciliation context and have the keyed elements register themselves with it or something.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to generate your Widget components separately from where they are rendered. For example:

```js
const WidgetContainer = () => {
  const widgetTree = useMemo(() => SOME_WIDGETS.reduce((tree, widget) => ({
    ...tree,
    [widget.name]: <widget.Widget someProps={someProps} />,
  }, {}), []);
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row1>
        {WIDGET_ROW1.map((widgetName) => widgetTree[widgetName])}
      </Row1>
    {/* etc... */}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

This means your widgets will be stored as pre-rendered JSX fragments, rather than being rendered each cycle. Obviously you will need to add any appropriate dependencies to the useMemo call, which may remove any benefits, but assuming the only state that changes is not present in the `widgetTree` dependencies, then this should prevent any lifecycle methods from being called.

It's worth noting that the lifecycle methods will still call when the JSX fragment is added to/removed from `widgetTree`.

Comment: Aaaaaand I'm just now realising this is a necro of the highest magnitude. Not sure if that's improper etiquette given that the original answer is quite outdated.