# Reactjs - Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. How to do that dynamically?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, key, unique, mongoose-schema

I know what the warning means, but how to actually make a dynamic key value?

I tried various methods but none worked. Maybe I can do a `key` value in each object in `mongoose schema` but is it a bad practice? I mean in real world apps what do they do?

`my component render`

```
  render(){
        const myNotes = this.state.Data;
        const listItems = myNotes.map((dynamicData)=>{
      return(
        <Fragment>
          <h3 className='col-12 title' key="12">{dynamicData._id}</h3>
            <div className=' col-6' key="13">
              <ul className ='list-unstyled ' key="1">
              <li className='items' key="2">items</li>
                <li key="3">{dynamicData.firstItem}</li>
                <li key="4">{dynamicData.secondItem}</li>
                <li key="5">{dynamicData.thirdItem}</li>
                {/* <li>Total Budget :</li> */}
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div className='dynamicData col-6' key="6">
              <ul className ='list-unstyled' key="7">
                <li className='prices' key="16">Prices</li>
                <li key="8">{dynamicData.firstPrice} {dynamicData.currency}</li>
                <li key="9">{dynamicData.secondPrice} {dynamicData.currency}</li>
                <li key="10">{dynamicData.thirdPrice} {dynamicData.currency}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <h3 className='col-12 totalprice' key="11">{dynamicData.tBudget} EGP</h3>
        </Fragment>
        )
    })

      return (
         <div className=' col-6 myNotesList ' key="14">
            <div className='row inNotesList' key="16">
          {listItems}
         </div>
         </div>
        )
    }
```

`Mongoose Schema`

```
var listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  currency:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength:3,
    default: "EGP"
  },
  _creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  firstItem: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  firstPrice:{
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    default: null
  },
  secondItem: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  secondPrice:{
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    default: null
  },
  thirdItem: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  thirdPrice:{
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    default: null
  },
  tBudget:{
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    default: null
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create unique keys for React elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549424/how-to-create-unique-keys-for-react-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install uuid
```

uuid will generate a unique key, now wherever you create a note object add an id to each note and call `uuidv4()`.

```
 makeNote = () => {
 const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
 const note = {note:"hello", id:uuidv4() }
 return note;
 }
```

When you map through your notes just do `notes.map(item => <div key={item.id}> {item.note} </div>`

Alternative to uuid you can use a function like

```
getNoteId = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999-1)) + 1;
```

then do inside the makeNote function `const note = { note:"hello", id:this.getPostId() };`

Comment: Why install a library for this when you can do it in multiple other simple ways?

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You're very welcome if you found my answer useful please upvote it.

Comment: i did but im under a 15 reputation so it's not publicly shown.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code:

```
myNotes.map((dynamicData)=>{return <Component key={dynamicData._id} />;})
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the parent element of each iteration needs to be keyed. You can set a key on the `<Fragment>` element, [as explained in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments).

As for the key itself, you can use any of the methods suggested here, but I think some may be a bit overkill, since creating an unique key can be an one liner which you can put wherever you find suitable (i.e., utility library, class method...):

```
uniqueId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
```