# If Using Index is Bad as ReactJs Key. Then What should I be using?

Tags: reactjs

I recently learned that using "index" for a key is actually bad practice and can lead to wrong data being shown.

I since then started to use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) version 4 to generate random keys but while I am writing this I am coming to the conclusion maybe I am using it wrong?

```
 <div className="container">
            {myStore.mapping.map((header, index) => {
              return (
                <MyComponent
                  key={index}
                />
              );
            })}
</div>

 <div className="container">
            {myStore.mapping.map((header, index) => {
              return (
                <MyComponent
                  key={uuidv4()}
                />
              );
            })}
</div>
```

In the above example I first am using Index and the second one I am using uuidv4().

Now in this particular example nothing is being added/removed to the mapping array so index in theory should not get out of sync and that's why I believe when I was using it I did not get the weird behavior of my browser jumping to the top.

In each of my component a dropdown is rendered and depending on screensize scrolling might appear. When I use uuidv4() as the key and I am say scrolled half way down the page and change a dropdown value, my browser will throw me back to the top of the page.

I believe this is because after every re-render a new id is generated and thus the code things everything changed and this is why for whatever reason the jumping to top happens.

This leads me to the question what should I be using? Do I have to always use uuidv4() inside the "mapping" object instead of generating it in the "map loop"?

Comment: This information is very well documented https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: "wrong data" will not be shown once you avoid using uncontrolled inputs. but anyway using index as a key will definitely affect performance if items are deleted or new one inserted in the middle of the list: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Comment: `index` is only bad if your list data is changing.

Comment: have u tried with the given answer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid using random keys.

Always use unique id from data as a key. If the data don't contain unique key then use index as key like below.

Use id from data as key

```
<div className="container">
            {myStore.mapping.map((header, index) => {
              return (
                <MyComponent
                  key={header.id}
                />
              );
            })}
</div>
```

Use index as key

```
<div className="container">
            {myStore.mapping.map((header, index) => {
              return (
                <MyComponent
                  key={`Key_${index}`}
                />
              );
            })}
</div>
```

For detailed answer take look at this SO question and answers [Different ways to add a key to JSX element in loop in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196127/different-ways-to-add-a-key-to-jsx-element-in-loop-in-react)

Comment: well should I just always make an id/key? Like should I go to my "mapping" object and use uuidv4 to generate a unique id for every object, even though it really would be just used for the key and not an id for identification on the server.

Comment: Also why did you put label "key" instead of just using "index" number.

Comment: You can generate unique id for each object in array in you preferred way and while iterating add the id as key. The reason I added key as label because we are not recommended to use index directly as a key so appending some text to the index while adding key is recommended. If you look at the link I shared in my answer that explains in detail about adding keys