# Generate custom IDs for input in React

Tags: reactjs

How can I generate custom IDs for input without using any packages/moduls outside of React?

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549424/how-to-create-unique-keys-for-react-elements/51428373) for unique keys using index, but as one user pointed out, while React documentation says you can do it that way:

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
  // Only do this if items have no stable IDs
  <li key={index}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

It's not wise to use [index for this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). Is there any other way I could generate unique IDs with React? Thanks!

Comment: The answer in the example you shared talks about all possible solutions

Comment: Your todos don't have id that's unique?

Comment: What's the need to reinvent the wheel? You can easily use [uuid - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: Got it! Thanks, people!

Comment: I totally agree with the comments. But I will leave one option here just in case
`(Math.random().toString(36) + Date.now().toString(36)).substr(2, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

In the react docs you link it's says: "We don’t recommend using indexes for keys **if the order of items may change.**"

So if you change the orders in your array (like sorting them) and you haven't a unique  propertie just give them one initial (when you create the array or directly after getting the array)

```
todos.forEach((todo, index) => todo.index = index);
```