# Unique key React, solution?

Tags: reactjs, key

How to pass key in this code?

`{result.map(book, key =>` I got stuck here. I tried several times but I can't!

```
          { 
             result.map(book => (
                    <div className="col-md-3 mb-5">
                        <div className="card card-body bg-light text-center h-100">
                            <img className="w-100 mb-2" src={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks !== undefined ? book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : ''} alt={book.title} />
                            <h3 className="text-dark card-title">{book.volumeInfo.title}</h3>
                            <h5 className="text-dark card-title">{book.volumeInfo.authors}</h5>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   ))
          }
```

Comment: `{result.map((book,index) => (<div key={index} className="col-md-3 mb-5">.....`
do it like that it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use unique key for the books (ID). It might be doing problems if you will delete the books for example.

I don't know your API implementation but it could look something like that:

```
 {result.map(book => (
    <div className="col-md-3 mb-5" key={book.id}>
        <div className="card card-body bg-light text-center h-100">
            <img className="w-100 mb-2" src={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks !== undefined ? book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : ''} alt={book.title} />
            <h3 className="text-dark card-title">{book.volumeInfo.title}</h3>
            <h5 className="text-dark card-title">{book.volumeInfo.authors}</h5>
            </Link>
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

React.Children.toArray solves this issue as it takes the job of assigning keys to children to itself. Do it like this

```
{React.Children.toArray(
result.map(book => (
                    <div className="col-md-3 mb-5">
                        <div className="card card-body bg-light text-center h-100">
                            <img className="w-100 mb-2" src={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks !== undefined ? book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : ''} alt={book.title} />
                            <h3 className="text-dark card-title">{book.volumeInfo.title}</h3>
                            <h5 className="text-dark card-title">{book.volumeInfo.authors}</h5>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                )))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key property must be unique in order to not break react rules. So I suggest you to use book.id if it has is property or array index with `map((book,index)=>{})`. Note that if you have multiple map in your code, actually in your entire app, this approach will probably fail as there’ll be more component with same key property.

So I suggest you to use a key with a prefix that prevent duplicates. For example

```
books.map((book, idx)=><Book key={`book_${idx}`} />)
```

This approach is not safe by default, so you need to be sure that no elements with the same key are generated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the parentheses.

If you want to use the item index as a key, you can try:

```js
{result.map((book, index) => <div key={index} ...>...</div>)}
```

But, using indexes for keys is not recommended. It would be better to use IDs from your data as keys.

More info about this: [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Answer (score 0):

Keys are one of the most important parts of the React Virtual DOM, especially if you have editable elements - [Official React Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#where-to-get-your-key)

TL/DR: choose one, on this order:

- id from your database: must be strong and unique (cannot be numeric)
- useId (a React Hook)
- nanoid (for older React versions)

Example with `useId`:

```js
import { useId } from 'react';

(...)

 return (
   <select
     value={selectedValue}
     onChange={this.onSelectedItemChanged}
     disabled={isDisabled}
   >
    {(collection ?? []).map((items) => {
      return (
       <option value={item.value} key={useId()}>
         {item.text}
       </option>
      );
    })}
   </select>
 );
```

For a more detailed answer, I recommend the read of the following response to this question: [StackOverflow How to create unique keys for React elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53309924/5936119).