# while running the react native app i got the error : Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the same code in two different components. I got the error in react native code  Encountered two children with the same key, `29270`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
How I can solve this error I don't understand what is the error and why to occur please help me to solve the problem

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList data={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderItem={({item}) => 
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress= {() =>this.props.navigation.replace('Test', { StudentUid: item1.uniquecode,  AccessToken: this.state.accessToken })} >
                                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.id} {item.firstname} {item.middlename} {item1.lastname}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                    />
                </SafeAreaView>

can  I use like this 

<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList data={this.state.dataSource}
                        renderItem={({item}) => 
                            <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} style={styles.item} onPress= {() =>this.props.navigation.replace('Test', { StudentUid: item1.uniquecode,  AccessToken: this.state.accessToken })} >
                                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.id} {item.firstname} {item.middlename} {item1.lastname}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                    />
                </SafeAreaView> 
Is this write code?
```

Comment: I think you want you will find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39549510/7088760).

Comment: I can't find a solution, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. supply a key to your child `TouchableOpacity` with `key={item.id}`
2. create a keyExtractor function like this

```
    const keyExtractor = (item) => {
      return item.id.toString();
    };
```

and define this function in your `Flatlist` with `keyExtractor={keyExtractor}`

Comment: can you explain it with my code? using 1st option.

Comment: well, solution 1 is code that you just add to your `TouchableOpacity` for solution 2 I would need your whole code, but I think it is self explanatory if you look into the documentation of `Flatlist`

Comment: <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} style={styles.item} onPress= {() =>this.props.navigation.replace('Test', { StudentUid: item1.uniquecode,  AccessToken: this.state.accessToken })} > is this write

Comment: I have edited my question please check it.