# how to write Foreach with out key in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, foreach

i want to loop in this array, and i don't have key in array

my array

```
const array = ['name1','name2','name3']
```

after that the proplem on console is

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`

my component

```
{
    items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div className="flex-shrink-0 py-1">
            <button
              key={}
              onClick={() => onFillter(item)}
              type="button"
              className="... tailwind css"
            >
              {item}
            </button>
          </div>
       );
    })
}
```

i try to added `math.random()` in key -> bad result
added number to array -> bad result

Comment: Why not use the item itself as key? `key={item}`

Comment: I hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39549510/16466946) helps

Comment: @kikon  The accepted answer to that link is a really bad idea using the index of the array, especially if the array gets mutated.

Comment: Mapping gives you a second argument called `index` which is just a numerical value for the item being mapped. That's what I use for the key. It would look like this:

    {
    items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} className="flex-shrink-0 py-1">
            <button
              key={}
              onClick={() => onFillter(item)}
              type="button"
              className="... tailwind css"
            >
              {item}
            </button>
          </div>
       );
    })
}

Comment: @Sako  It's best avoided, if the array gets mutated your in for funky results.  like Ostone0 has pointed out, just pass the Object, objects are unique already.. Job done.

Comment: @Keith right, I recommend OP to read the full post

Comment: i am using it but not work

Comment: now i using it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511264/19694485 
and work 100%

Comment: Did you not read the comments for that link??, and what issue did you have with @0stone0 recommendation?.