Adding separator in list of items in reactjs
I was trying to render an list of items in react, and I need a separator between each element in this list.
But I'm getting unique key error:
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I even tried using the uuid library to generate a unique id for card and separator as well...
This is my code:
function Gallery({ items }) {
  return (
    <section className="image-gallery py-10">
      <div className="card-container grid gap-20">
        {items.map((img, i, arr) => {
          return (
            <>
            <ImageCard
              key={uuidv4()}
              imgSrc={img.src}
              imgAlt="Image"
              link={img.link}
              text={img.text}
              title={img.title}
              reverse={i & 1}
            />
            { i + 1 < arr.length && <Separator key={uuidv4()} /> }
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Gallery;


The key should go on your fragment instead.

Might be worth adding that if you have an id attribute on the img object, it might be a better choice for a key. There's a great discussion on keys at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549424/how-to-create-unique-keys-for-react-elements.

You probably already realize this, but just in case: you definitely should not use key={uuidv4()} in "real" code, because that tells React that you want to drop the old components and create new components every time that Gallery is re-rendered. That is very expensive!


Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

In your case, your child is the fragment (<></>), not the <ImageCard />, so you need to add the key prop to it.
Note: You can't use fragment's short syntax, so you have to use it this way <React.Fragment key={id} />
On top of that, using uuid as key is not optimal, as that means every component will be considered a new instance on each re-render, having to re-draw them, even if none of its props have changed.
Instead, you may want to try using any of this options if available:

id - assuming each item has its own id
src - assuming they do not repeat)

If none of them applies, consider using the index parameter i, which is less expensive than uuid if your list does not gets modified.
Updated code:
function Gallery({ items }) {
  return (
    <section className="image-gallery py-10">
      <div className="card-container grid gap-20">
        {items.map((img, i, arr) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={img.id}>
              <ImageCard
                imgSrc={img.src}
                imgAlt="Image"
                link={img.link}
                text={img.text}
                title={img.title}
                reverse={i & 1}
              />
              { i + 1 < arr.length && <Separator /> }
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Gallery;

