# React - persist element across parents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to avoid unmounting/remounting an element when it is moved between parents?

I have tried applying relevant `key`s to all elements, but since [`key`s are only sibling-unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428962/how-unique-should-a-react-component-key-be) this has little impact.

```js
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("A new item was created");
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("I mounted");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("I unmounted");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>Item</li>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemList: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(
      this.pickNewList.bind(this),
    2500);
  }

  pickNewList() {
    let newList;
    do {
      newList = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    } while (newList === this.state.itemList);
    console.log(`Moving item from ${this.state.itemList} to ${newList}`);
    this.setState({
      itemList: newList
    });
  }

  render() {
    const uls = [...Array(3)].map((v, i) => {
      return (
        <ul key = {i}>
          <li>Non-item</li>
          {this.state.itemList === i ?
            <Item key="item" />
            : undefined} 
          <li>Non-item</li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {uls}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(( <
  App / >
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In my specific use case I am looking to animate the movement using [react-flip-move](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/react-flip-move), but since the element is unmounted/remounted every time, it is not registered as a move.

Comment: Why don't you make your `key` unique? For example `<Item key={"item_" + i} />`

Comment: @FiriceNguyen That would be counterproductive. The goal is to tell React that the item is the same as the previous item - not that it is different.